# How to add placeholder and require attr to dsp input tag

Tags: html, atg

I am new to the ATG please help me below query

I have an ATG tag

`<dsp:input value="${email}" id="email" type="email" bean="ProfileFormHandler.value.login" maxlength="256" onkeypress="javascript:checkSubmit(event,loginSubmit);"/>`

for this tag i need to add placeholder and require attributes .I tried adding there attribute. after this my application is not working.

Please help me .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `dsp:tagAttribute` tag to add extra attributes to a `dsp:input` tag.

For example:

```
<dsp:input value="${email}" id="email" type="email" bean="ProfileFormHandler.value.login" maxlength="256" onkeypress="javascript:checkSubmit(event,loginSubmit);">
    <dsp:tagAttribute name="placeholder" value="Enter email here..." />
</dsp:input>
```

For reference, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPageDevGuide/html/s1336dsptagattribute01.html

Comment: If you need to format or translate the placeholder, you can: 
<fmt:message var="ph" key="someLogin.email.placeholder" />
<dsp:input ...>
    <dsp:tagAttribute name="placeholder" value="${ph}" />